# How to work around HTML not importing full HTML as XMLObject

Tags: import, html, xml

I'm trying to parse some data out of the HTML for a form. Here's a simple one

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[
  {"Name" -> "String", "Email" -> "EmailAddress"},
  TemplateApply["Thanks ``! Your submission went through.", {#Name}] &
  ],
 "testForm",
 Permissions -> "Public"
 ]
```

It's easy enough to get the raw HTML body

```
body = URLRead[CloudObject["testForm"]]["Body"]
```

and I see a large `<script>` in the header + some stuff in the body.

But if I use `Import` that all goes away

```
ImportString[body, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}]

XMLObject["Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version" -> "1.0", 
   "Standalone" -> "yes"]}, 
 XMLElement[
  "html", {"lang" -> "en", {"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns"} -> 
    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}, {XMLElement[
    "head", {}, {XMLElement["title", {}, {"
      Wolfram
    "}], XMLElement["meta", {"charset" -> "utf-8"}, {}], 
     ...,
     XMLElement[
      "script", {"defer" -> "defer", "type" -> "text/javascript", 
       "src" -> 
        "/dist/dyn/vendors~Dialogs~account~authLanding~dashboard~deployedView~\
directoryPlaceholderLanding~error401Permi~17e11331-4e693e624e6d42331857.js"}, \
{}], XMLElement[
      "script", {"defer" -> "defer", "type" -> "text/javascript", 
       "src" -> "/dist/dyn/formView-4db6f811488735b8a396.js"}, {}], 
     XMLElement["script", {}, {"
if(typeof LAZY_RESOURCES === 'undefined'){LAZY_RESOURCES={}}
"}]}]}], {}]
```

I tracked the issue down to `` System`Convert`HTMLImportDump`FixFile `` but I'm not sure how I should best patch this since the damage happens on the Java side (the function uses `JLink`)

Comment: Saved the file and opened it VSCode, the syntax coloring was not right (in Sublime it was ok), after formating the HTML code, the Import works fine. I could trace the problem to line 224 (starts with `!function(e){function d(d) ...`), If you delete it, the import will also work fine.

Comment: @BenIzd nice to know, but unfortunately that's beyond my control. I found a workaround that I'll post in a minute

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick workaround using `"Python"` with `"beautifulsoup4"`, a third-party module to format the HTML text.

1. First install `"beautifulsoup4"`/`"bs4"` ([pypi](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/))
2. create a function to use the module

```
prettify = ExternalFunction["Python", "
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def temp(text):
    return bs(text).prettify()
"]
```

apply it to strings:

```
ImportString[text, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}] // Depth
(* Out: 9 *)

ImportString[prettify @ text, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}] // Depth
(* Out: 27 *)
```